# dropdown in meteor? using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

my html-code:

```
<div id="playerselect">
 <div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

on the page i can see the button, but on click it doesnt show the dropdown menu.
as this is like the code from the bootstrap-doc i have no idea why i cannot see the actual dropdown.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: you don't need javascript if you use `data-toggle="dropdown"`

Comment: okay thx. i delete the javascript part. still when i click the dropdown, i dont get dropdown

Comment: Have you added bootstrap to your app by running `meteor add bootstrap` inside the apps directory?

Comment: i thought meteor comes with some native-like bootstrap support. anyway it did what u said and: IT WORKS! thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making my comment above into an answer.

Using bootstrap in Meteor requires the command `meteor add bootstrap` to be run somewhere in the project tree to add the bootstrap package.  Without it Meteor will not have the bootstrap javascript or css files.

`meteor list --using` in the project's directory will list which packages you are using.